# Naming a chord in the first movement of Mozart's K. 331?

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, chord-theory, analysis

How could one name the first chord in measure three in Mozart's A-major piano sonata K.331, first movement?

[image: Mozart Sonata in A Major, K. 331, mm. 1-4]

It looks like a F#-minor-7th-chord without the fifth, i.e. something like a substitution of the submediant VI for the tonic I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having thought about this for a while (and being unsatisfied with the lack of detail in my assertion that a D sounds more idiomatic than a C♯), I am posting an answer to elaborate.

My reasons for calling this chord a (modified) IV6 chord include:

- I've always heard the F♯ to E interval as an unresolved `7-6` suspension.
- Typical figures for a bass line ascending `^6 ^7 ^1` are `6 6 [5]` (or `6 6/5 [5]`), yielding `IV6 V6 I` or `IV6 V6/5 I` (see the example in Wikipedia's article on the [rule of the octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_the_octave), which harmonizes the ascending major scale as `I V4/3 I6 II6/5 V IV6 V6/5 I`).
- The submediant (`vi`) is typically grouped with the tonic (`I`), reflecting its function in a deceptive cadence.  To prepare the dominant, one typically expects `ii` and `IV`.  (See the Wikipedia articles on [harmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(music)) and the [submediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submediant).)
- The first variation supports this interpretation; it has a D in the melody at this point.
- A similar bass line appears in Mozart's variations on *Ah, vous dirai-je maman,* without the inner pedal, and it is invariably the bass of a `IV6` chord.

Comment: This is great. When I can, I'll post a similar case for C#.

Comment: @Aaron I'll be curious to see what you come up with.  I did find one bit of evidence that I neglected to cherry pick, that some might read as supporting C♯, but I don't think it's structural.  The actual harmony in that case is, I believe, ii4/3.

Answer (score 2):

It's F# minor without the fifth. The E is a pedal tone.

One way to establish this, is to play the opening measure without the E. The overall sense of harmony is unaffected, which helps demonstrate that the E is independent of the harmonic progression even though it is often a participant in it.

The core harmonic progression is

- I: First measure
- V65 (or vii<sup>o</sup>): Second measure
- vi-V6 (or vii<sup>o</sup>): Third measure

In other words, the progression is defined by the bass motion: 8-7-6-7-8.

Comment: I would call it a IV6 chord.  That is, if I had to add a note there, I would add a D, not a C♯.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @Anna Are you asking why I think the E is a pedal tone; why I think it's a C# minor chord; both; or something else?

Comment: Aaron, I was referring to phoog. @phoog So again, why would you call it a IV6 chord?

Comment: @Anna because a D sounds more idiomatic than a C♯.